# Corrupted window control theme on Unity

Tags: unity, gnome, 14.04, themes, window-decoration

I have a question related to themes in Ubuntu 14.04. Whenever I try to apply a few themes such as Adwaita or Zukitwo, the window controls are not accurately themed and look out of place. I have added a couple of screenshots, one is with Adwaita and the other with Zukitwo.

[image: Adwaita]

[image: Zukitwo]

I observe this behavior only with Unity, the themes work fine with other desktop environments such as Gnome shell and cinnamon. I have tried resetting gnome and Unity settings, but that doesn't help. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I actually was having the same problem myself. Restarting unity will not change anything. There are plenty of themes available which will work in Ubuntu 14.04 however. The [Moka project](http://mokaproject.com/) themes are exceptionally well designed . I also have found the [Nitrux](http://www.noobslab.com/2013/06/nitrux2-nitrux-and-inx-icons-for.html) icons to work quite well in Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Ubuntu 14.04, Unity uses [CSS themed window decorations](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/02/ubuntu-1404-unity-gets-new-gtk3-css.html) and some themes like Adwaita (well, actually most themes) don't support it yet.

One of the popular themes that support CSS window decorations is [Numix](http://numixproject.org/).

Comment: Thanks, I follow webupd8 and had read the article. I wanted to confirm whether it really is related to CSS theming, or was it just because of some corruption. By the way, I do use Numix (and Moka for that matter) occasionally.

Comment: I guess these issues arise since these themes (e.g., zukitwo) stick to gnome releases and compatibility, and do not backport to Ubuntu changes. 

For those interested: installing the latest release of zukitwo will solve the window controls issue, but there will/could be other theming problems.

Comment: Is there any way to use Adwaita in Unity in 14.04 ?